# How to save and rename XML file automatically based on its object name

Tags: windows, xml, batch-rename

I have a hundreds XML files but with a random file names.
They named like this:

- Bt_01.XML
- Bt_02.XML
- Bt_03.XML
- Bt_04.XML

But they supposed to named like this:

- Button_Accessories.XML
- Button_Menu01.XML
- Button_Menu02_new.XML
- Button_NewLobby_Header.XML

In each XML file, they has their own XML names.

For example, *Button_NewLobby_Header* in **Bt_04.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResAssets>
    <Object0 Class="Resource_Button" ID="1" Name="Button_NewLobby_Header">
        <Shape0 Name="" path="assets/button/Bt_A01.tga"  width="2048" height="2048" X="0" Y="0">
        </Shape0>
    </Object0>
</ResAssets>
```

I want to know how to save and names them automatically based their object name.

Comment: I do not want to write this automation script for you, but I could give you some clues. Let us say that you would use [the Bourne-Again Shell-Scripting environment](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/bash.html) that runs inside [the Cygwin environment](http://www.cygwin.org/) on the Microsoft Windows family of operating systems. You could `grep` for the `Name="Button_NewLobby_Header"` character string. Make a regular expression out of it. Extract the `Button_NewLobby_Header` character string. Use it in order to rename the XML file using the `mv` command. Good luck!

Comment: @MihaiDobrescu Installing cygwin solely to achieve this is spectacular overkill. There are not only Windows versions of grep (and awk and cut) but also PowerShell and VBScript.

Comment: True, @Richard, this is entirely true. It has been merely an example. I bet that there are people out there who can perform this solution merely using the Microsoft Windows Command-Line Preprocessor (`Cmd.Exe`). I am eagerly waiting for them.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 3.0 solution:

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:for-each select="collection('my/lib/select=*.xml')">
    <xsl:result-document href="{/*/Object0/@Name}.xml">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```